# How does one switch tracks in Windows 8.1's XBox Music app?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-surface, playback, windows-rt, xbox-music

[image: XBox Music Now Playing]

In the XBox Music app (both app and Windows completely updated) I tried playing a folder full of MP3s from a USB HDD. In the screenshot above the track *Sometimes* is currently playing (indicated by the small green spectrum analyzer icon to the left).

Now suppose I want to start playing the sixth track *So Hard*, how do I do it without pressing the Next Track button five times? Double-clicking (using touch) doesn't work and selecting the track by swiping left or right doesn't show any *Play Now* option in the bar that pops up from the bottom. Cannot believe the default music player app is *so* bad! :o

Answer (score 1):

Kind of mute now that this has been addressed since this post... but it wasn't that hard to begin with. You simply selected the track and then pushed the play button next to the song name.... wasn't very hard to figure out?

Comment: Nothing is "mute", and there was no Play button next to each track in the Now Playing view that I magically couldn't see. Keep your Smart Alec answers to yourself please.